# SQL Table Dropped Weeks Ago Only Erroring Now

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I ran into an issue last night that I cannot quite figure out. I'm no SQL expert and after doing countless google searches I'm still nowhere close to figuring out why this is happening.

About six weeks ago a table was supposedly dropped from my database, not by me. After this table was dropped all the views that depended on it still functioned properly. This table was unused but still had a handful of dependencies as I can see now in the Object Dependency viewer in SQL Management Studio. We implemented a few updates to out SQL Server 2012 last night and the server was restarted.

At about the time these updates were going on we started to receive a bunch of errors all revolving around this missing table that was deleted 6 weeks ago. After recreating the table everything was fine.

We're currently going through the updates to see if they could have effected it in any way. Does anyone know if there is any sort of caching that could have been going on that I'm not aware of? I'm really stumped as to why this worked for those 6 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Was the table a temp table?  (A table name preceded by #.)  If so, SQL sometimes caches temp tables.  That could explain why the views worked.  Then, when you updated your server and restarted it, the temp table caching was cleared.

Comment: It wasn't a temp table. It was a table that was used in the past but is no longer relevant.

Comment: It sounds like the table still existed in the sysobjects table and the views ran off that.  If you know how the table was dropped (via script, via management studio), you could try recreating the scenario on one of your test servers and see if you get the same results.

Comment: I can confirm that there is some kind of SQL caching going on. I was able to recreate the issue on a dev website with out dev database. I'm just not entirely sure why it's going on.

Comment: Half the battle won now that we know there is caching going on.  I am trying to remember if there is some setting when SQL was first installed  or if this is something that you can turn off.  The caching is making sure the three basic rules are met - all the 1.  database objects referenced in the statement exist
2.  that they are valid in the context of the statement, 
3.  that data modification statements do not violate any data integrity rules.

Comment: This could apply: It could have been running from SQL's query plan:
SQL Server automatically caches query plans and try to reuse them whenever possible. For many applications (such as OLTP transactional applications), plan reuse is a very good thing since it avoids unneeded compilations that may take much time to complete each time a query is executed. SQL Server caches query plans (execution plans based on parameter assumptions) but not execution contexts (execution plans based on the actual parameters values).   From:  http://www.sqlbadpractices.com